# Angular2 RxJS - Creating an observable for a mocked service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a mock file containing a collection of Tasks, each of which has a due date. Currently (below) I have the creation of a simple observable that, when subscribed to, returns the collection of mocked Tasks. What I'm failing to figure out is how I can process the flat array of Tasks to group them by their due date, returning a structure like;

```
// Current data structure (unstructured)
[{due: "2016-01-01"}, {due: "2016-01-01"}, {due: "2016-01-02"}, ...]

// Desired structure for consumption
{
  "2016-01-01": [{...}, {...}],
  "2016-01-02": [{...}, {...}, {...}],
  "2016-01-03": [{...}]
}
```

My current observable creation code is as follows;

```
// Service...
tasks: Observable<Task[]>;

// init() called from the constructor
private init() {
  this.tasks = Observable.create(observer => {
    observer.next(mockTasks);
  });
}

getTasks() {
  return this.tasks;
}
```

Which is consumed in my component as follows;

```
// Component...
ngOnInit() {
  this.taskService.getTasks().subscribe(tasks => {
    this.tasks = tasks; // Contains the collection of tasks as expected
  });
}
```

This works fine - I get my full array of tasks back as expected. I've tried using the `groupBy` operator to achieve the above but the observable created via `Observable.create()` does not appear to have that method available. I've been referring to [this resource](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html) to attempt to achieve this and I notice that `Observable.from()` is used instead of `.create()`, however this also does not appear to be an available function in my service.

1. Is using RxJS operators (such as `groupBy`) the way to go with formatting the data as above (and how can this be achieved)? Or should this be manually formatted?
2. Regarding either answer to 1 - where should this take place?

Thanks!

Comment: It is always as simple as `Observable.from(mockTasks)` or `Observable.of(mockTasks)`. It depends on what output you need, because `observer.next(mockTasks)` creates an observable with single array value, not with several object values. There's no desired method available, it should be added manually with `import rxjs/add/observable` and `import rxjs/add/operator`, otherwise you will end up with several basic methods that were initially added by Angular core modules.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing several things, I guess. Observables always have the factor time in it, so you're emitting things over time through the help of an observable. If you only want to group things in a static array, observables are the wrong approach.

In your case you have several dats

```js
const tasks = 
  [ {due: "2016-01-01"}
  , {due: "2016-01-01"}
  , {due: "2016-01-02"}
  ];
```

If you're about to put them in an Observable, that's possible but it would just output the array once and that's it.

```js
const observable = Rx.Observable.of(tasks);
observable.subscribe(x => console.log('All at once', x));
// output: All at once [ {due: "2016-01-01"},  {due: "2016-01-01"}, {due: "2016-01-02"} ];
```

If you want to distribute them in time - and now we're getting closer to what Observables are for - you can do this also

```js
const observable2 = Rx.Observable.from(tasks);
observable2.subscribe(x => console.log('One after the other', x));
// output: 'One after the other' {due: "2016-01-01"}
//         'One after the other' {due: "2016-01-01"}
//         'One after the other' {due: "2016-01-02"}
```

Now let's assume we have a data source that once in a while provides a new task and we want to group them over time.
This is what it would look like:

```js
const observable3 = Rx.Observable.from(tasks);
observable3
  .scan((acc, obj) => {
    let oldValue = acc[obj.due] || 0;
    acc[obj.due] = ++oldValue;
    return acc;
  }, {})
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// output: { 2016-01-01: 1 }
//         { 2016-01-01: 2 }
//         { 2016-01-01: 2, 2016-01-02: 1 }
```

So depending on your needs Observables might be the right thing. If data is distributed in time it's perfectly possible to group them as shown above. I've [uploaded the code to jsbin](https://jsbin.com/quvemebiwi/1/edit?js,console) to play around with it.